# Unsupported Operating System Pop Up while running MySQL Workbench in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench

**Whenever I open my MySQL Workbench, I am getting a pop of message saying "Unsupported Operating System. ..... Please keep this in mind if you run into problems.".**

I am using

1. MySQL Version = mysql Ver 8.0.23-0
2. Ubuntu Version = ubuntu0.20.10.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

**How can it be fixed?** :)
*I have attached the screenshot of the pop-up* [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ignore that warning for now. The supported OS list will be updated with the next release (8.0.24).